# Nodejs - Read values of array as number instead of string

Tags: node.js, arrays, string, casting, integer

I created an array inside my own class in nodejs to store real values.

```
this.values = new Array();
```

and almost every second a new value is pushed to this array.

```
this.values.push(Number(dataset.c).toFixed(4));
```

Finaly I have a function where I need to provide the array in the argument list to do bollinger band calculation. This function need an array filled with real or integer values but in my array every value is stored as an string.

Is it possible to change this storage behaviour or how can I 'typecast' all the values in this array?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using the map-Function.

```
this.values.map(Number)
```

did the job.